# How do tamed wolves interact with the passive mob limit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know there is a limit to the number of passive mobs that can be in the game at any one point. (I remember reading somewhere that the number is something around 15, but I'm not sure.) What I'm wondering is how tamed wolves interact with it. For example, take the following scenario: you have 3 less tamed wolves than the passive mob limit. The game logic attempts to spawn 4 chickens.

Will the game just spawn 3 chickens instead? Or will it spawn 4 and remove one of the tamed wolves you currently have? Also, does this mean if you have filled the entire mob limit with tamed wolves, no other passive mobs will be able to spawn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the Minecraft version at the time of writing this...

Tamed wolves are not a passive mob and **they do not have any limit**, so they will **not** affect the passive mob limit (because if they were counted in the passive mob limit there would be a limit on the number you can tame.)

Passive mobs (a pig, for example) will NEVER attack you, even if you attack them.

Wolves are actually tame, meaning they follow and protect you.

Short answer:

*Tamed wolves do NOT affect the passive mob limit in any way.*

Answer (score 3):

Actually, tamed wolves do influence the passive mob count.

If you don't believe me, you can try it. Tame as many wolves as you can (say, 15), then light only one patch of grass at night and walk far enough away for things to spawn

You can camp all day and night and nothing will spawn. The reason why there's no limit to wolves is that you can tame them, make them sit, walk far enough that they aren't loaded in memory (and then not part of the passive mob count) get some more, and walk back. But if the wolves are always near you, they count toward the passive mob count.

Answer (score 0):

Tamed wolves never de spawn, unless killed, you can make them sit, and walk 500 blocks away, spawn 100 creatures, and when you get back, they'll still be there.

Comment: so what does your answer imply about other passive mobs wrt the limit?

Comment: Well, afaik, the passive mob limit isn't effected by the wolves

Comment: @raybritton then you should include this in your answer. But references beyond _afaik_ would be even better ;)

Comment: That's why I didn't include it. Based on some tests I did, with 3 wolves following me, I've come across 3 sheep, 2 chicken, 1 pig and 3 cows around a torch.

Comment: Actually, if you walk more than 50 blocks away, they'll teleport to you.

Comment: @Ullalluloo Not if they are sat down. I got my 3 to sit at my house, and travelled about 200 blocks, without them following me, upon returning they were all still there.

Comment: Yes, but what if you have maxed out wolves following you? Will **no** passive mobs spawn while you're walking around?

Comment: To use afaik again: afaik, there's no limit to the number of wolves, try and get 15 and see if any other mobs spawn?

Comment: People have successfully tamed 50+ wolves.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question at all.